# Testing if css prop is supported by the client. Code breaks after repetitions

Tags: javascript, css, prop

I’d be very thankful if maybe someone else got a clue on why my code breaks / infinite loops when I run it multiple times, purposely resulting in a result 'false'

Warning your browser may stop responding if you run the code with an invalid/unsupported css prop.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Test if a style property is supported by the browser.</p>

<form onsubmit="myFunction(); return false">
<input type="text" id="prop" style="width: 180px;" placeholder="e.g. box-shadow">
<button type="submit">Try it</button>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
String.prototype.isSupported = (function() { 
    var div = document.createElement('div'), 
        vendors = 'khtml ms o moz webkit'.split(' '), 
        len = vendors.length; 

    return function(prop) { 
        prop = this.valueOf(); 
        if(prop in div.style) return true; 
        prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) { return val.toUpperCase(); }); 
        while(len--) { 
            if(vendors[len] + prop in div.style) { return true; } 
        } 
        return false; 
    }; 
}) ();

function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("prop").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = input.isSupported();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the **len** value every time your isSupported() function is called. Right now your code suggests that you are collecting the length only when isSupported() method is declared. So, after the first call, your while loop made the len variable to 0. Then any subsequent call decremented the len variable further more and took it to -1, -2, and so on. In JS minus values are truthy. So, your while loop is getting stuck. All you need to do is to reset the len variable when the function gets called. Here is the fixed code:
https://jsfiddle.net/f3kpdwu4/4/

```
String.prototype.isSupported = (function() { 
    var div = document.createElement('div'), 
        vendors = 'khtml ms o moz webkit'.split(' '), 
        len = vendors.length; // it runs only once

    return function(prop) { 
        len = vendors.length; // refresh it on every call
        prop = this.valueOf(); 
        if(prop in div.style) return true; 
        prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) { return val.toUpperCase(); }); 
        while(len--) { 
            if(vendors[len] + prop in div.style) { return true; } 
        } 
        return false; 
    }; 
}) ();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What a simple logic error. I couldn’t figure it out at all. The while-loop is subtracting every step. I just didn’t know it also overwrites the len variable itself. I’m more used to PHP, hence why I couldn’t grasp the problem.